# AntiForgeryToken HtmlHelper throwing NotImplementedException when run within a RazorGenerator class

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using RazorGenerator to unit test my Razor/MVC3 per David Ebbo's post here http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/unit-test-your-mvc-views-using-razor.html and every time I attempt to use the AntiForgeryToken HtmlHelper (with no method arguments), it throws a NotImplementedException.  What gives?  As best I can tell, both my cshtml file and the view.generated.cs the correct method in System.Web.Mvc.dll, in the System.Web.Mvc namespace's HtmlHelper class. I've downloaded the latest source for the RazorGenerator project and don't see the word "forgery" contained within it anywhere, so I don't think I'm getting confused about exactly which HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken() method I'm hitting.

The code sample of my unit test follows:

```
    [Test]
    public void Index_RendersView()
    {
        var view = new Index();
        // For test to succeed, this should not throw exception            
        view.RenderAsHtml();
    }
```

Pretty basic.  I'll spend some time digging under the hood to figure this one out and will follow up here if I figure this one out, but in the meantime I'm wondering if anyone else has encountered this and already worked out a solution.

Comment: Looking at the exception call stack ... What method does it happen in? The constructor or another?

Comment: Excellent! I looked at that but was naive not to have paid closer attention:  The exception is actually thrown at a call several steps deeper than just .AntiForgeryToken().  It is actually thrown in System.Web.HttpRequestBase.get_Cookies(), so that would be the place where I will start digging.  I have no idea how the RazorGenerator handles its HttpContext internally.  So it would be cool if someone out there had already figured out a solution, but once again, I'll dig and follow up before too long.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to pass my view's ViewContext.HttpContext a Mock per Scott Hanselman's instructions on how to do so, and have setup the HttpRequestBase mock's .Cookies property return a new HttpCookieCollection(), and am still getting the notimplementedexception, so no dice so far, but I bet I'm close to licking this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corresponded with David Ebbe, one of the (or, the) project owners on CodePlex, and he altered something within the RazorGenerator project source to fix this.  Remarkably, he had it fixed within less than 1/2 hour of me asking the question on the CodePlex board.

I'm going to vote to have this question deleted since I don't think there's any value to keeping it around this site.